# how to force a result prior to executing next method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, async-await, azure-functions

**How do we force an execution of `ReadAsStringAsync(?`**

Inside my azure function, I'm `awaiting` the body of the request:

```
            var body = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

and immediately afterwards I am using `body` for the next method:

```
            var hasRootNode = XmlValidator.HasRootNode(body);
```

This is the definition of `HasRootNode`:

```
public static bool HasRootNode(string xml)
```

It seems like it is NOT reading the entire string prior to calling the `HasRootNode` method.

**How do we force an execution of `ReadAsStringAsync(?`**

Comment: Question: Why would you need to read a string from a request? Do you mean response?

Comment: "It seems like it is NOT reading the entire string..." It is. Please describe the actual symptoms of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReadAsStringAsync() 'eats the data' as has been suggested, the content is being processed as a stream and since the data has been consumed by the message formatter the Position of the stream is already at the end.

In order to use ReadAsStringAsync() you first need to reset the content stream Position to the beginning.

```
 XmlValidator.HasRootNode(new System.IO.StreamReader(req.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()).ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: is that the same as `var body = req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`  ??

Comment: another words we cant simply use `.Result` ??

Comment: I gave you multiple tips in one answer. Never use .Wait() and never use .Result. Check out this educational video about common TAP mistakes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=av5YNd4X3dY&t=156s